# Why does this code cause a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I execute this code in my `applicationDidBecomeActive` callback.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
     [self showMainWindow];
}


- (void) showMainWindow{
      PushNotificationTabBarController *pushNotificationTabBarController = [[PushNotificationTabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushNotificationTabBarController" bundle:nil];
      self.viewDeckController.centerController = 
          pushNotificationTabBarController; // registered for Notification via addObserver...
}
```

The `setter` is defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIViewController* centerController;
```

`IIViewDeckController` property in my `AppDelegate`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IIViewDeckController *viewDeckController;
```

I found out that I have 2 `PushNotificationTabBarController` objects when I close and re-enter the app, with no reference to one of them, like a memory leak. However I dont understand why this code is causing it because to me it seems ok. I'm using `ARC`.

Comment: Can you show where the code is called?

Comment: A better way is to surround this whole thing with if (self.viewDeckController.centerController == nil ) { insert code here }

Comment: I certainly know it´s not nil, `self.viewDeckController.centerController` contains another viewController, but this `showMainWindow` wants to set it to this particular `pushNotificationTabBarController`.

Comment: Why is your centerController property strong?

Comment: it´s not my code, it´s third party software :(

Comment: the center.viewDeckController is third party I mean.

Comment: Just to double check I understood `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIViewController* centerController;` is not your code? Also, can you add the definition of the `viewDeckController` property.

Comment: yes, that is correct. I´m editing my post.

Answer (score -1):

Before setting pushNotificationTabBarController check for self.viewDeckController.centerController object. If it exists, release and assigned to nil and assign new object of 'pushNotificationTabBarController'

```
 id controller = self.viewDeckController.centerController;
    if (controller) {
 [controller release];
  controller = nil;
}

  self.viewDeckController.centerController = pushNotificationTabBarController;
```

Comment: I´m using automatic reference counting. I can´t send `release` messages

Comment: Okay. Then in dealloc method check for any timers validations & any objects not removed.

Comment: Help me with this you just gave me a clue: `pushNotificationTabBarController` has added observers. Could this cause the problem?